# Override serilog properties based on source/context

Tags: asp.net, logging, hangfire, seq, serilog

Is there any way to override either a sink or a property in serilog based on source or context.

For instance, I have this setup in an asp.net mvc core 2 project:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Fatal)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.Seq("https://url", apiKey: "sdfasdfasdfas")
```

However, i just added Hangfire to my application, and would like to either use a different apikey for my Seq sink, or push a modified property to the sink based on "Source"="Hangfire." - exactly like you can override the minimumlevel based on "Source"="Microsoft".

As far as I can tell I can't inject a separate logger for hangfire at configuration, since the configuration method doesn't take parameters and defaults to the static log:

```
services.AddHangfire(config => config.UseSerilogLogProvider()
```

Comment: Do all of the events from Hangfire come tagged with a `Source` or `SourceContext` property that makes them easy to identify?

Comment: Yes. That's why I was hoping I'd be able to use something similar to the minimum level override

Comment: Check out https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map - mapping on a `bool` "is hangfire" might be one way to achieve this.

Comment: did you get final solution ?

Comment: @PreguntonCojoneroCabrón No - I decided to simply override the minimumlevel of Hangfires logevents to fatal just like Microsoft. I may revisit this, if I decide I need more logging info from Hangfire, but so far that isn't the case